# Why do I get "Error: Reliable snapshot overflow" while loading maps?

Tags: team-fortress-2

This happens to me about 80% of the time. The error appears right at the end of the map loading screen—when it says, "Loading client..." I get a popup: "ERROR: Reliable snapshot overflow".

So I have to reload the map (which takes much less time than originally).

This happens when I choose a server in the server list (a map in progress), and when I am already on a server and there is map change.

What could cause that? How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Typically this issue is a memory error of some sort** and can be caused by a variety of things almost always related to the map/server that you are connecting to including but not limited to [losing your spot on the server](http://gwf.site.nfoservers.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=669), [certain plug-ins](http://forums.srcds.com/viewpost/109109#pid109109), [poorly optimized maps](http://www.teamfortress2fort.com/forums/t/ERRORReliableSnapshotOverflowWTF-6194.aspx?p=1#252903), [bandwidth issues](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showthread.php?p=30232171#post30232171) and [possibly even actually from snapshots and demos](http://www.teamfortress2fort.com/forums/t/ERRORReliableSnapshotOverflowWTF-6194.aspx?p=1#53299). Valve has not provided much on this issue so explanation and resolution seems dubiously anecdotal at best. The majority of the cited cases that you will find relate to issues with the connection and map more than anything. **The only suggested solutions that seem to work are try different maps/servers, use a better connection (this includes running fewer processes that can eat bandwidth ie.torrents, software updates, antivirus software, etc.), [lower your game settings](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showthread.php?p=30304091#post30304091) or [ask the owner of the server for a map reset](http://www.wiremod.com/forum/installation-malfunctions-support/4414-reliable-snapshot-overflow.html#post39187).**